# Call control in Teams tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've seen some screenshots suggesting that it is possible to accept / hold / reject / hangup a call from within a tab in the Teams client. However, i cannot find any reference about such capabilities. I thought of deeplinks or the javascript client SDK, but either I am not looking good enough, or it just isn't there.

Does anyone know if and if so, how this is possible?

Comment: This is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This item remains on the backlog in Teams UserVoice,
Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/)